# Why is the bootstrap component is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, components

Just want to check why is the bootstrap code is not working in a react component? I don't understand how it will work. Whenever I check the website it is always an error

```html
import React from 'react';

function LoginForm() {
    return (
    <form>
        <form class="mb-3"></form>
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
        </form>
        <form class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
        </form>
        <form class="mb-3 form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
        </form>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    )
}

export default LoginForm
```

Comment: what is not working?  where is your `bootstrap-compnent`?

Answer (score 0):

To use Bootstrap with React, I recommend you to install **react-bootstrap** or **reactstrap** package :

**react-bootstrap** ([Link](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction))

```
npm i react-bootstrap | yarn add react-bootstrap
```

**reactstrap** ([Link](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap))

```
npm i reactstrap | yarn add reactstrap
```

**DON'T FORGET TO...**

1/ Install Bootstrap

```
npm i bootstrap | yarn add bootstrap
```

2/ Import Bootstrap

In **src/index.js** add this : `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`